# How to update line item properties in shopify

Tags: jquery, shopify

I want to add custom info in line item properties using jQuery.
[Line item properties](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/line_item#line_item-properties) which i can update on click of a checkbox.
I have tried this but it is not working

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/cart/update.js",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"updates":{ "1234567890": { "properties":{ "Someprop": "Somevalue" }}}}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close!

The `update` endpoint can update multiple products at once, but cannot change the line-item properties.

You're looking for the `change` endpoint, which can modify a single line in greater detail.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "/cart/change.js",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"id":"1234567890", "quantity": 1, "properties":{ "Someprop": "Somevalue" } }', 
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

NOTE: The data must contain either "line" (1-based index of item's position in the cart.items array) or "id" (which can either be the item's `id` or `key` value).  I recommend updating using the `item.key` for the ID field when using both the /change and the /update endpoints: `id` is just the variant ID, and when using line-item properties the same ID can therefore be repeated across multiple lines.  The `key` is guaranteed to be unique.

Additionally, when hitting the /cart/change endpoint, if you do not specify the quantity parameter Shopify may default the line's quantity to 1. To be safe, I would recommend always explicitly passing the line's current quantity.

Note that Shopify will *replace* the line-item properties for the edited item with the line-item properties object that you supply. Per Corey's comment, the safest thing to do when updating a line item's properties is to get the existing properties for the line, update the value(s) that need updating, then hit the `/cart/change.js` endpoint with the updated object.

---

Additionally, per Bart Coppens' observation in the comments, an empty properties object is ignored by Shopify. This makes deleting all properties from a line item a bit problematic. The best workaround I have been able to come up with so far is to use a placeholder value whose key begins with an underscore, as the leading underscore causes Shopify to hide the property on the Checkout.  (For example, I might use `_validated: true/false`).  If your theme doesn't already hide properties with a leading underscore, find the properties loop (usually beginning with `for p in item.properties`) and add the following:

```
{% if p.first.first == '_' %} {% continue %} {% endif %}
```

Comment: Just a warning, the answer above would delete any existing line item properties and only leave the Someprop line item property remaining. Say for example you had Someotherprop = Someothervalue as well on this line item, the code above would delete that line item property. There's no way to just update 1 line item property's value if that line item had multiple properties. You would have to somehow get all existing line item properties, loop over them to find the one that you are updating, and then make sure you are posting all of the other line item properties as well as the updated one.

Comment: Thank-you for adding that warning, Corey! It's something I've said many times, but apparently I neglected to bring it up again in this answer.

Comment: Thanks @DaveB. The above approach works for replacing (adding or removing) properties as long as the remaining set of properties is not empty. How would you update the properties to remove all properties from a line item? Passing null or an empty hash does not seem to work. It seems that only results in the 'properties' argument being ignored (only the quantity is changed). What am I missing?

Comment: @BartCoppens - You're correct, an empty properties object is ignored.  You need to pass at least one value for Shopify to recognize it. What I have done in the past is decide on some placeholder value to use.  Shopify ignores properties whose keys begin with an underscore on the checkout (and it is quite easy to do the same on your theme if it doesn't already), so I would name my placeholder value something like `_validated` or similar.